# use smtp.js in react

Tags: reactjs, smtp, syntax-error

im trying to use smtp.js in react, the problem is that when i use the code in the cdn to save it into a varible, so i can use the method send(), it says there is a syntax error, when it shouldnt happend

```
Line 18:83:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused- 
expressions
Line 18:338:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused- 
expressions
Line 18:561:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused- 
expressions
Line 18:807:  'XDomainRequest' is not defined                                        no-undef
```

ive been trying to import the code as a module, create a new Script tag, but nothing seems to work

Comment: Please translate your question title as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include

```
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
```

in between the `<head></head>` of your index.html file of your React App (you should load all scripts at the end).

Once you have done this, you can access `Email` by using `window.Email`.

Now you should be able to send an email by entering your SMTP credentials using the following code:

```
window.Email.send({
    Host : "smtp.yourisp.com",
    Username : "username",
    Password : "password",
    To : 'them@website.com',
    From : "you@isp.com",
    Subject : "This is the subject",
    Body : "And this is the body"
}).then(
  message => alert(message)
);
```

Where you put it is up to you. You could put it within a useEffect so it gets called when a particular Component is mounted to the DOM.